# Why does LINQ throw a null reference error on Count() if Any() is true?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question - why do I get a null reference exception at the `.Count()` method of this IEnumerable if the `.Any()` returns true?

```
 Logger.Normal("{0}", targetWorkflow.GetStages().Any() ? "any is true!" : "any is false");
 Logger.Normal("{0}", targetWorkflow.GetStages().Count());
```

Error:

`StackTrace = [ at Sth.Workflow.<GetStages>d__13.MoveNext()XX at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource]`

To be honest, I would expect that the `Count()` method should return at least 1 if `.Any()` is true, while if `Any()` was false, it would return 0?

Let me know where I am wrong, please.

Also - please note that I am not trying to fix the actual problem, I am trying to understand why `Any() == true` does not ensure that the collection is healthy and 'countable'.

Comment: You probably can only enumerate this collection once.  Try calling ToList and then doing your operations against that.

Comment: Is it possible `GetStages()` is returning null on the second call?

Comment: Is it possible that this would work? `targetWorkflow.GetStages?.Count()`

Comment: @Casey - I get a null reference when calling the `ToList()` method - anyway, why would this happen?
@AlfieGoodacre - no, sadly not, same error

Comment: Is the code of `Sth.Workflow` yours? If so, what is the definition of `GetStages`? If not yours, where did you get it from and what version do you use?

Comment: @Bartosz have you used it in context, you would have to remove the first line and then in the logger have `Logger.Normal("{0}", targetWorkflow.GetStages()?.Count() ?? "");`

Comment: @PatrickHofman - the code is mine (sort of) and the signature of GetStages is pretty standard `public IEnumerable<IWorkflowStage> GetStages()` - also, this works OK if I have another object (so the problem is somewhere with `targetWorkflow`...

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: You are asking about a simple side-effect of a deeper problem, but there is no code for or information about that actual issue. Unanswerable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman  - this is not true, have a look at the answers below.

Comment: No, Henk is right. Servy just points out the source of the problem. Not the solution to the actual problem.

Comment: @PatrickHofman  - and that is what I was after - precisely this bit - "Any can stop as soon as it gets the first item, which is why it's not throwing any exception, but Count needs to iterate the entire sequence in order to get its result." of Servy's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GetStages()` appears to be throwing an exception internally within its own code when generating some item that isn't the first item in the sequence.  `Any` can stop as soon as it gets the first item, which is why it's not throwing any exception, but `Count` needs to iterate the entire sequence in order to get its result.

There is some bug internally in the `GetStages()` method (or some violation of it's intended usage that you're making) that is unrelated to the code that you've shown.

Comment: Also explains why `ToList()` throws an exception. Nicely done!

Comment: Good catch (+1) from me :)

Comment: Indeed. The problem is in the implementation of the iterator, somewhere in these the problem arises. In fact it is just a plain old `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Bartosz yes, it should, but you have to fix the actual issue. Debating if calling another method will not trigger the coding issue behind it is useless.

Comment: @Bartosz It would work any time `Any` would work.  WIthout knowing the actual cause of the error we couldn't know for sure; it's possible that there are some circumstances in which even the first item would cause the exception.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - that's all good, I am not trying to fix the issue, I am trying to understand the strange behaviour.

Comment: @Bartosz IEnumerable is resolved lazily, so until you actually try and enumerate the whole list all the code in GetStages is not run.